# The link for deleting item returns undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, routes

This is the relevant part of the routes:

```
resources :photos, :path => '', :only => [:show, :new, :create, :destroy, :edit] do
  ...
end
```

And I am added into a view a link for deleting a photo:

```
  <%= button_to 'Delete', @photo, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

But this view returns the error:

```
undefined method `photo_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faef8172060>:0x007faef87a7908>
```

The **destroy** method is the method generated by scaffold. What do I have wrong?

**EDIT:** `rake routes` output:

```
                root           /                                      photos#index
              search GET       /search(.:format)                      photos#search
      voteup_user_photo GET    /:user_id/:id/voteup(.:format)         photos#voteup
    votedown_user_photo GET    /:user_id/:id/votedown(.:format)       photos#votedown
            user_photos POST   /:user_id(.:format)                    photos#create
         new_user_photo GET    /:user_id/new(.:format)                photos#new
        edit_user_photo GET    /:user_id/:id/edit(.:format)           photos#edit
             user_photo GET    /:user_id/:id(.:format)                photos#show
                     DELETE    /:user_id/:id(.:format)                photos#destroy
```

Comment: Run `rake routes | grep photo` and add the output from it to the original question; that would probably help.

Comment: Hi Prakash, please, see the modified OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you have a nested route (path needs `:user_id` and `:id`). Try passing the path parameters explicitly:

```
button_to 'Delete', { :user_id => @user.id, :id => @photo.id }, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to include the `:action` in the options hash as well.

Comment: You can also do `button_to 'Delete', user_photo_path(@user, @photo), method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?'`